# Carregar reCaptcha de um site diferente em minha aplicação WPF/XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, recaptcha

Estou trabalhando em um sistema que faz o download dos arquivos XML automaticamente desse [site](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaRecaptcha.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=). Porém esse site usa captchas de validação, e para isso oferecíamos duas opções para nossos clientes: usar api's como o anticaptcha (o que gera custos adicionais) e digitar o texto eles mesmos. Porém, recentemente o site foi atualizado e agora é usado o reCaptcha. A parte da api conseguimos resolver sem problema.

O que não estamos conseguindo fazer é renderizar o reCaptcha em nossa aplicação (que é feita em WPF/XAML).

Acredito que deva ser possível fazer isso, pois é assim que o AntiCaptcha funciona (usando pessoas reais para quebrar os reCatpchas).

O que eu preciso fazer para que a aplicação renderize o reCaptcha e capture a resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, tive que usar o cefSharp para carregar a pagina que continha o reCatpcha, e injeção do javascript do próprio cefSharp para remover os elementos desnecessários e deixar apenas o captcha visível.

Para capturar a resposta, deixei uma thread assíncrona em javascript rodando, "escutando" o campo 'g-recapcha-response' até ser diferente de vazio, no caso, quando o usuário tinha preenchido o captcha. Então salvei o valor do campo em uma variável e terminei a implementação.